# int64_t conversion to 'long double' issue

Tags: c++

The following code produces the shown output and I'm confused ... I'm using Intel compiler version 2013 beta update 2 `/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.0.030/bin/intel64/icpc`:

```
// all good
int64_t fops_count1 = 719508467815;
long double fops_count2 = boost::static_cast<long double>(fops_count1);
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", fops_count1); // OK outputs 719508467815
printf("%Le\n", fops_count2);         // OK outputs 7.195085e+11

// bad! why this?
int64_t fops_count1 = 18446743496931269238;
long double fops_count2 = boost::static_cast<long double>(fops_count1);
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", fops_count1); // OK outputs 18446743496931269238
printf("%Le\n", fops_count2);         // FAIL outputs -5.767783e+11 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< WHY?
```

Comment: Maybe this value is too big even for a long double?

Comment: What's this `boost::static_cast`? You can't use a keyword as name of something.

Comment: @H2CO3: It should fit in `long double` just fine; but not in `int64_t`.

Comment: I'm assuming this is aimed at either i386 or x86_64 platforms, where a `long double` has 80 bits of precision. (On many platforms, the size varies. On some, `long double` is no wider than a `double`. I mention this for completeness' sake.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the `boost::static_cast`, which I don't understand, a 64-bit signed integer can't represent the number you showed, but

18446743496931269238 - 2<sup>64</sup> = -576778282378

I.e. this is the value you get when a two's complement 64-bit signed integer wraps around.

Now what's that `boost::static_cast`?

Comment: @Giovanni: thanks, but while that involves a `static_cast` it can't be what the OP is using. the OP's syntax is invalid in standard C++. `static_cast` is a keyword; it can't be used as  a name.

Answer (score 1):

```
int64_t fops_count1 = 18446743496931269238;
```

This is signed overflow, which is UB. The maximum value of an `int64_t` is on the order of 2^63, which is definitely less than this value. Seems like your processor implements wraparound, giving the negative value you see.

Comment: Technically `the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised`, not undefined.

Comment: Really? I thought that signed overflow was flat out UB.

Comment: @DeadMG: It's UB if the result of an expression can't be represented by the expression's type (5/4); however, an integral conversion gives an implementation-defined value if the result can't be represented (4.7/3).

Comment: @Dave: You're quoting the C standard; in C++, it's simply "the value is implementation-defined".